Seven circles puzzle
I am thinking for quite a while about a geocaching puzzle called "Seven Circles", which probably has something to do with geometry:
https://shorturl.at/KB0lM
There are coordinates of 6 points given (5 waypoints + listing coordinates):

N 50° 41.840 E 014° 07.252
N 50° 41.315 E 014° 06.280
N 50° 40.315 E 014° 06.504
N 50° 41.840 E 014° 08.630
N 50° 40.840 E 014° 08.840
N 50° 39.843 E 014° 07.680

I suppose, one needs to find the 7th point somehow from these 6, but how? Maybe it should be placed in such a way that it is possible to draw 7 circles centered at these points so that they touch each other pairwise? But is this even possible for any arbitrary 6 points?
Another idea is that this could be related to the "Seven circles theorem":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_circles_theorem

Hi and welcome to Puzzling! Any chance you could provide a link to the cache page too? There may be useful additional context there, either in the geocache description or hiding among old Found logs. Thanks :)

I edited the question and added the link.

The arrangement of the circles in the geocache description image suggests that the seventh circle is centered within the other six, though the coordinates don't quite fit the geometry. The image is clearly a view from nearby castle ruins, though this probably isn't helpful. The radio tower in the distance can also be identified, and is certainly irrelevant.

I thought the image with 7 circles in the description could hint to the version of the 7-circles theorem, as there are several of them with different placements of the circles: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SevenCirclesTheorem.html
